# Chrome Extension open new tab via link

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension to list all of the servers some of my co-workers and I deal with daily. However, I'm getting stuck on something simple; I can't seem to get my link to open a new Chrome tab for the server.

**`manifest.json`**:

```js
{
    "name": "Servers",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Servers List",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "servers.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"]
    }
}
```

**`popup.js`**:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", function(){
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://www.google.com" });
    });
});
```

**`servers.html`**:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Servers</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <h3>iPortal</h3>
            <ul>
                <li> <a id="myLink">PTMIPS06</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've done the `chrome.tabs.create` piece directly in the console, and it works, so I know that isn't the issue. I've also tried other ways of getting the click events to work, but I haven't been successful. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) for Chrome extensions. Carefully.

Done? Then you will know that a popup page and a background page are not the same thing. They are two separate documents, one always open but invisible and the other open only while popup is shown.

Now, what happens in them?

- In the background page, you have a blank HTML file and your `popup.js` script. The code executes, but there is no element `#myLink` in it, throwing a fatal error on `addEventListener`.
- In the popup page, you've got your static HTML, but no scripts. So your link does nothing.

Instead of adding `popup.js` to the background page, you should include it in the popup with a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That Architecture Overview was just what I needed.  I didn't realize there was a difference between adding it as a background file in the manifest, and adding it directly on the page.  Saved that page as a bookmark!  It is now working.  Thanks again!

Comment: It's a great page overall, but sadly not much advertised in the documentation.